# What is the greatest remainder if you divide a 2-digit number by its digit sum

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I just found this problem and tried to solve it.

I wrote $x=90a+b$ and tried to maximize the function $f(a,b)=\frac{9a+b}{a+b}$ but did not come to any solution.  Then I considered $10a+b = x\pmod{a+b}$ which simplified to $9a = x \pmod{a+b}$.  Then I just tried some numbers.  The biggest remainder I could find was $13$ since $98 = 13 \pmod{17}$.  However, there has to be a more sophisticated way to determine this.  Another question would be, if there even is a generalization for $n$-digits.

Comment: What about $79$? Trying things seems like the reasonable thing to do, we fairly quickly run out of things to try.

Comment: Guess I overlooked 63 = 15 (mod 16). How did you determine that value? And how about the same question for n-digits? Thank you for your contribution.

Comment: Except that the digit sum of $63$ is $9$ and $63 \equiv 0 \pmod 9$  I think you meant $79$

Comment: Forgot to tell that, I considered 9a = x(mod a+b) which is equivalent to 10a+b=x(mod a+b)

Comment: @Deavor: Just mentally ran down the list.  I  can't think of anything useful for $n$-digit numbers. The answer will probably be not far from $9n$.

Comment: Alright. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have found $98 \equiv 13 \pmod {17}$, you only have to consider numbers with digit sums $14$ and above, even $15$ and above if you want to beat $13$.  There are not many of those.  We get $$\begin {array}{c | c} \text {n}&\text {rem} \\\hline 99&9\\98&13\\97&1\\96&6\\95& 11\\89&4\\88&8\\87&12\\86&2\\79&15 \end {array}$$ and now that we find $79 \equiv 15 \pmod {16}$ we are done.

Comment: Hmm, neat approach. Do you think there is a way which does not need bruteforce?

Comment: No, the relationship between numbers and the sum of their digits is rather random, so I suspect you are down to what I would call intelligent brute force.  The intelligent comes from realizing that you only need to check numbers with large enough digit sums.